# powershell function switch param with string array

Tags: powershell

I'm struggling to understand the outputs of the below function

```
function testApp
{
    param(
        [string] $appName,
        [switch] $sw = $false,
        [string[]] $test,
        [string[]] $test2
    )

    Write-Host $appName - $sw - $test - $test2
}
```

1. testApp -appName "TestApp" -sw $true -test "one", "two" -test2 "three","four"

Output: **TestApp - True - one two - three four**

2. testApp -appName "TestApp" -sw $true -test "one", "two"

Output: **TestApp - True - one two - *True***

The first output is as expected. But I cannot understand why the second output has "True" for the test2 array when I did not pass it. Can anyone help me in understanding the reason for the behavior? Thanks.

Comment: PLEASE format your code. right now it is nearly unreadable. the how-to is linked on the page where you created your Question.

Comment: the reason for that stray `True` is your misuse of the `[switch]` parameter. [*grin*] when you add that `-sw $True` you are flipping the `sw` to TRUE [it is FALSE by default] AND you are sending in a value that is not assigned to anything. since you did not directly assign anything to `$Test2` in the 2nd example, the surplus `$True` gets passed to the remaining parameter - the `-Test2` parameter.

Comment: Yeah, when using a [switch] you do not give it a default value.  It will test $true if specified in the call, and $false if not specified.  I had a hard time understanding that when I was first writing functions.

Comment: To add to the other comments, if you want to specify a value for a switch parameter you do it like this: “-sw:$true” - that is “hyphen switchname *colon* value”. This syntax is different to non-switch parameters that separate parameter name and value with whitespace, and is useful if your switch value comes from a variable - e.g. “-sw:$myVar”.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>To summarize and complement the helpful comments on the question by [Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey), [Matthew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8507473/matthew) and [mclayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156906/mclayton):</sup>

#### `[switch]` parameters in PowerShell (aka *flags* in other shells):

**[`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter) parameters are meant to *imply* `$true` vs. `$false` by their *presence*** in an invocation: e.g., passing `-sw` *by itself* signals `$true`, whereas *omitting* `-sw` signals `$false`.

- **It *is* possible to pass a Boolean value *explicitly*, for the purpose of passing a *programmatically determined* value; e.g.: `-sw:$var`**

  - **Note the required `:`** following the switch name, which tells PowerShell that the Boolean value belongs to the switch parameter; without it, PowerShell thinks the value is a *positional* argument meant for a *different* parameter (see below).
  - *Caveat*: Commands *may* interpret `-sw:$false` differently from *omitting* `-sw`; a prominent example is is the use of common parameter `-Confirm:$false` to override the effective `$ConfirmPreference` value.

    - If you need to make this distinction in your own code, use `$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('sw') -and -not $sw` to detect the `-sw:$false` case.
- ***Do not assign a default value*** to a switch parameter variable: while technically possible, the **convention is that switches default to *`$false`*** (which is a `[switch]` instance's default value anyway); that is, a `[switch]` parameter should always have *opt-in* logic.

**A `[switch]` parameter variable effectively behaves like a *Boolean* value** in most contexts:

- That is, you can say `if ($sw) { ... }`, for instance.
- If you need to access the wrapped Boolean value explicitly, access the **`.IsPresent` property** (note that the property name is somewhat confusing, because in a `-sw:$false` invocation the switch is still *present*, but its *value*, as reflected in `.IsPresent`, is `$false`).

  - An example of where `.IsPresent` is needed is the use of a Boolean as an implicit array index, notably to emulate a ternary conditional<sup>[1]</sup>: `('falseValue', 'trueValue')[$sw.IsPresent]`; without the `.IsPresent`, the effective Boolean value wouldn't be recognized as such and wouldn't automatically be mapped to index `0` (from `$false`) or `1` (from `$true`).

---

Ultimately, your problem was that you thought `$true` was an argument *for `-sw`*, whereas it became a *positional* argument *implicitly bound to the `-test2` parameter*.

`[switch]` parameters never *need* a value, so the next argument becomes a separate, positional argument - *unless* you explicitly indicate that the argument belongs to the switch by following the switch name with `:`, as shown above.<sup>[2]</sup>

#### *Positional* vs. *named* argument passing in PowerShell:

<sup>**Terminology note**: For conceptual clarity the term *argument* is used to refer to a *value* passed to a declared *parameter*. This avoids the ambiguity of using *parameter* situationally to either refer to *the language construct that receives a value* vs. *a given value*.</sup>

- ***Named* argument passing** (binding) refers to explicitly placing the target parameter name before the argument (typically separated by a space, but alternatively also and / or by `:`); e.g., `-AppName foo`.

  - The *order* in which named arguments are passed *never matters*.
- ***Positional* (unnamed) argument passing** refers to passing an argument *without* preceding it by the name of its target parameter; e.g., `foo`.

  - The passing is positional in the sense that the relative position (order) among other unnamed arguments determines what target parameter is *implied*.
- `[switch]` parameters are the *exception* in that they:

  - are typically passed by *name only* (`-sw`), implying value `$true`, and if a value *is* passed, *require* `:` to separate the name from the value.
  - *never* support *positional* binding.
- **You may *combine* named passing with positional passing**, in which case the named arguments are bound first, after which the positional ones are then considered (in order) for binding to the not-yet-bound parameters.
- PowerShell functions are *simple* functions by default. **In order to *exercise control over positional binding*, use of the `[CmdletBinding()]` and / or `[Parameter()]` attributes is necessary (see below), which invariably turn a simple function into an *advanced* function**.

  - Making a simple function an advanced one has larger behavioral implications (mostly beneficial ones), which are detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51912471/45375).
- **By default, PowerShell functions accept positional arguments for *any* parameter** (other than those of type `[switch]`), ***in the order in which the parameters were declared***.

  - Additionally, *simple* functions accept arbitrary *additional* arguments *for which no parameters were declared*, which are collected in the automatic `$args` array variable.
- **To prevent your function from accepting *any* positional arguments *by default***, place a **`[CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$false, ...)]`** attribute above the `param(...)` block.

  - Since this makes your function an *advanced* one, this also disables passing arbitrary *additional* arguments (`$args` no longer applies and isn't populated).
  - As an aside: when you implement a *cmdlet* (a command implemented as a *binary*, typically via C#), this behavior is *implied*.
- **To *selectively* support positional arguments**, decorate individual parameter declarations with a **`[Parameter(Position=<n>, ...)]`** attribute (e.g, `[Parameter(Position=0)] [string] $Path`)

  - Note: Whether you start your numbering with `0` or `1` doesn't matter, as long as the numbers used reflect the desired ordering among all positional parameters; `0` is advisable as a self-documenting convention, because it is unambiguous.
  - Attribute `[Parameter(Position=<n>)]` is an explicit opt-in that *selectively overrides* `[CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$false)]`: that is, the latter disables positional binding *unless explicitly indicated* by individual parameter declarations; in fact, the latter is *implied* by the former, in that **once you use *one* `[Parameter(Position=<n>)]` attribute, you must use it on all other parameters you want to bind positionally as well**.

---

<sup>[1] Note that PowerShell [Core] 7.0+ supports ternary conditionals natively: `$sw ? 'trueValue' : 'falseValue'`</sup>

<sup>[2] In effect, `[switch]` parameters are the only type for which PowerShell supports an *optional* argument. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58848736/45375) for more information.</sup>