# What is the effect of "-ScriptBlock" in "New-Module -AsCustomObject"

Tags: powershell, syntax, parameter-passing

I am new with powershell and I had been researching how to create custom objects.

With "New-Module" I always find results like "New-Module -AsCustomObject **-ScriptBlock**".
Like this for example:

```
$myObject = New-Module -AsCustomObject -ScriptBlock {
    function myFunc(){
       return "myFunc";
    }
}
```

but when I try without "-ScriptBlock":

```
$myObject = New-Module -AsCustomObject {
 
    function myFunc(){
       return "myFunc";
    }
}
```

it appears to have the same effect to me. I get a custom object with a function myFunc in both cases.

Am I missing something? Or actually it will have no difference in this particular case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
New-Module -AsCustomObject -ScriptBlock { function myFunc(){ return "myFunc"; } }
```

passes the [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) `{ ... }` as a ***named* argument** to the `-ScriptBlock` parameter. That is, the target parameter is *explicitly named*.

PowerShell commands can choose to alternatively support ***positional* arguments**, where the target parameter is *not* named, and instead the relative *position* among *all unnamed* arguments implies the target parameter.

The [`New-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-module) cmdlet's first positional parameter is indeed `-ScriptBlock`, which means that
**`-ScriptBlock` before the `{ ... }` block can be *omitted* here**, which is why **your two commands are *equivalent***:

```sh
# Same as above, except that -ScriptBlock is *implied*, positionally.
New-Module -AsCustomObject { function myFunc(){ return "myFunc"; } }
```

(Note that the `-AsCustomObject` *switch* parameter (flag) is by definition *named*, so it has no impact on *positional* parameter binding.)

---

You can **learn which of a given command's parameters are positional** by looking at its [syntax diagrams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Command_Syntax), which you can obtain with `New-Module -?` or `Get-Command New-Module -Syntax`:

```sh
# Note: PowerShell commands can have multiple *parameter sets*, with
#       distinct parameter combinations.
#       Here, I've omitted the 2nd parameter set that doesn't apply to
#       your call, because it doesn't use the -Name parameter.
PS> Get-Command -Syntax New-Module

New-Module [-ScriptBlock] <scriptblock> [-Function <string[]>] [-Cmdlet <string[]>] [-ReturnResult] [-AsCustomObject] [-ArgumentList <Object[]>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

The `[...]` around a parameter *name* tells you that a given parameter accepts a *positional* argument, and in the case at hand that only applies to `-ScriptBlock`, so it is the first and only positional parameter in that parameter set.

---

To **learn more** about:

- **how to read syntax diagrams**, including a helper function that programmatically lists a command's positional parameters, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65617895/45375)
- **declaring your own positional parameters** when authoring functions and scripts, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60250136/45375).