# Make Start-Process respect Verbose preference of parent script

Tags: powershell

Here are my scripts

**Parent.ps1**

```
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
Param()
Write-Verbose 'Triggering Child Process...'
Start-Process PowerShell.exe '.\Child.ps1'
```

**Child.ps1**

```
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
Param()
Write-Verbose 'Child Process Triggered.'    # I want output from this line to be displayed
Write-Output 'Child Process Triggered.'
Start-Sleep 10
```

I'm calling the parent script as below

```
powershell Parent.ps1 -Verbose
```

Actual outpt:

```
VERBOSE: Triggering Child Process...
Child Process Triggered.
```

Desired Output:

```
VERBOSE: Triggering Child Process...
VERBOSE: Child Process Triggered.
Child Process Triggered.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to run `.\Child.ps1` via another PowerShell instance, in a new window, asynchronously:

```
Start-Process PowerShell.exe "-c .\Child.ps1 -Verbose:`$$($VerbosePreference -eq 'Continue')"
```

<sup>Note the use of `-c` (`-Command`) to signal what PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) parameter the command string is passed to, to distinguish it from `-f` (`-File`). While not strictly necessary, because `-c` is the default in Windows PowerShell (`powershell.exe`), it helps to clarify, especially given that *PowerShell (Core) 7+* (`pwsh`) now defaults to `-f`.</sup>

- When you invoke your `Parent.ps1` script with `-Verbose` (`-vb`), PowerShell translates this switch to a script-scoped `$VerbosePreference` variable with value `Continue`.
- To propagate a switch value - on or off - programmatically, you can follow the switch name with `:` and a *Boolean*, e.g. `-Verbose:$true`.

  - **Caveat**: While something like `-Verbose:$false` is *typically* the same as *not passing the switch at all*, there are exceptions, and this is one of them: `-Verbose:$false` explicitly overrides a *caller's* `$VerbosePreference` preference variable to deactivate verbose output - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60250136/45375).
  - That said, this isn't a concern in your case, given that you're launching a new PowerShell instance, and there's no session-internal caller.
- The above uses an [expandable string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) to translate the value of `$VerbosePreference` into the appropriate Boolean; note that the subexpression (`$(...)`) is prefixed with `` `$ ``, i.e. an *escaped* `$` character to be retained *verbatim*, because *stringifying* a Boolean results in either `True` or `False`, so the `$` prefix is needed to turn it back into a Boolean the way it needs to be represented as a literal *in source code*.

Note that if you were to invoke `.\Child.ps1` *directly* from your parent script, it would automatically "inherit" the parent's `$VerbosePreference` value (it would see the same value by default, due to PowerShell's dynamic scoping).

---

**A note on `-c` (`-Command`) vs. `-f` (`-File`) and PowerShell (Core) 7+:**

For invoking a PowerShell *script file* (`.ps1`) via the CLI, it is generally sufficient and preferable for robust passing of verbatim arguments to use the `-f` (`-File`) parameter; `-c` (`-Command`) is only needed if you need the command string to be evaluated *as PowerShell code*.

**In Windows PowerShell (`powershell.exe`), the `-f` parameter doesn't recognize Boolean argument values**, unfortunately, which is why `-c` is used in the solution above. This limitation has been fixed in PowerShell (Core) 7+ (`pwsh.exe`).

See also:

- [Guidance on when to use `-c` (`-Command`) vs. `-f` (`-File`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57443822/45375)
- An [overview of PowerShell's CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68136129/45375); covers both editions.