# In Powershell, how to make a command line flag with an optional String Arguments?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to port some perl code to powershell.  However, I don't know how to implement optional arguments in powershell?

In perl, My code does something like this below, which allows me to call the script as:

```
myscript -z -in myin
```

or with optional argument:

```
myscript -z myz -in myin
```

Here's how I do this in perl:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
# PERL CODE
use Getopt::Long;

GetOptions(
    'z:s'   => \$zip,
    'h'     => \$help,
    'in=s'  => \$input_dir,
);

# Using a colon (:s) instead of the equals sign (=s) 
# indicates that the option value is optional. In 
# this case, if no suitable value is supplied, 
# string valued options get an empty string ''.
```

However in powershell i'm not sure how to get the functionality of ":s" in perl. Here's my Powershell code that attempts to do the same thing:

```
# Powershell
param(
    [string] [optional???] $zip = "hello",
    [switch]$h,
    [string]$input_dir
)
```

Is there a way to do this in powershell?

Comment: Unfortunately, PowerShell (as of v7.2) does _not_ have support for parameters whose argument is _optional_. A - suboptimal - _workaround_ is available for a _single_ parameter of this type. See the [linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58838941/powershell-special-switch-parameter).

Answer (score 1):

Powershell parameters are optional by default. Mandatory parameters need to be marked with `[parameter(Mandatory=$true)]`.
See also [about_functions_Advanced_Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.2) in Microsoft docs.

Comment: Not the Parameter...  the Argument to the parameter... For example, given parameter "-z myz",  the "myz" part is the argument to the parameter "-z".  I want to know if I can my "myz" optional but still have "-z"

Comment: Passing an empty string is still acceptable unless you have `[NotNullOrEmpty]` as well. Alternatively you could specify another parameter set with that parameter as a switch instead. The link provided may give you enough to do so.