# powershell script to select directory

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, cmd, terminal

I would like to create a powershell function or cmdlet that would allow me to quickly navigate to files and function like the example below. Could someone enlighten me to what the "/D" would be called? Is it a parameter?

```
C:\Windows\system32> folder /help
Usage: Select directory folder [/? | /Username | /S | /D] 

No args    Display help. This is the same as typing /?.
/?         Display help. This is the same as not typing any options.
/Username  Change to the "Username" directory
/S         Change to the "scripts" directory
/D         Change to the "desktop" directory

C:\Windows\system32> folder /username
C:\Users\username> folder /S
C:\Users\username\desktop\scripts> folder /D
C:\Users\username\desktop>
```

This is what I have so far. This will only take me to the desktop directory, how would I write this to have it named "folder" and add the modifier/parameters?

```sh
function desktop { cd "C:\users\username\desktop" }
```

This functions as following:

```sh
C:\Windows\system32> desktop
C:\Users\username\desktop>
```

Comment: This is unclear. Can you tell us what you want to type into the prompt and what you expect to happen? The way this reads it seems you want to type `banana` into the prompt and be moved to a folder called `banana` .

Comment: A cmdlet would be a little more difficult given that it's compiled and written in a .Net language. Anyways, this frankly isn't too hard to do as long as you specify/hard-code the paths you'd want to switch in-between. To answer your question though, yes, `/d` is a parameter but, so are the others. We can refer to them as *switches*, or *flags* since they are binary and are either there, or not. Building a function with switches like `folder.exe` is totally doable and I suggest looking into the `$env:` drive where you will find variables like `$env:userprofile` :)

Comment: @anothervictimofthemouse no, that's what the existing code does. Read the above script "help" and pseudo code.  Folder would be the command the /D for desktop would be the parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in PowerShell lingo `/D` is called a *parameter* (other shells may call it an *option* or a *flag*, as [Abraham Zinala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14903754/abraham-zinala) notes), but note that PowerShell only accepts `-` as the parameter-name sigil, so it would have to be `-D` (on invocation you're free to use `-d` or `-D`, because parameter names aren't case-sensitive in PowerShell).
A parameter that acts as an on/off switch (called a *flag* in other shells, i.e. one that doesn't take *an argument*), is called a *switch [parameter]* in PowerShell.

Note that while you *can* define single-letter parameter names in PowerShell, it is customary to use longer, descriptive names, e.g. `-Desktop`:

- Thanks to what PowerShell calls *elastic syntax*, you can still use just `-d` on invocation, as long as the `d` *unambiguously* implies the full target parameter name (e.g., `-Desktop`).
- Alternatively, you may explicitly declare `-d` to be an alias for `-Desktop`, by decorating the parameter declaration with an `[Alias()]` attribute.

Here's a sample function that works slightly differently from what you specified, but operates in a more PowerShell-idiomatic way:

- Parameter-less invocation changes to the current user's home folder.

  - To target a different user's home folder, pass the username to the  `-u` / `-UserName` parameter.
- Whatever user's home folder is chosen in a given invocation can optionally be *combined* with either `-Desktop` / `-d` or `-Scripts` / `-s`, in order to change to the desktop / scripts folder for the targeted user.
- To show help, use `-?` (or `Get-Help folder`), which PowerShell supports by default, showing the command's syntax.

  - To add a verbal description to the help, you can use comment-based help to your function - see the conceptual [about_Comment_Based_Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comment_Based_Help) help topic.
- [`Push-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/push-location) rather than [`Set-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location) (whose built-in alias is `cd`) is used to change location, to enable returning to the previous folder with [`Pop-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/pop-location) (whose built-in aliases are `popd` and `popl`)
- The function below is a so-called *advanced* function, which means that it acts like a (binary) cmdlet; for more information, see the conceptual [about_Functions_Advanced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) and [about_Functions_Advanced_parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced_parameters) help topics.

```sh
function folder {
  [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Default')]
  param(    
    [Alias('u')]
    [string] $Username
    ,
    [Alias('s')]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Scripts')]
    [switch] $Scripts
    ,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Desktop')]
    [Alias('d')]
    [switch] $Desktop
  )

  $targetFolder = 
    if ($Username) { 
      Join-Path (Split-Path -LiteralPath $HOME) $Username
    } else {
      $HOME
    }

  if ($Scripts) {
    $targetFolder += '\Desktop\Scripts'
  } elseif ($Desktop) {
    $targetFolder += '\Desktop'
  }

  Push-Location -LiteralPath $targetFolder
}
```

Sample calls:

```sh
folder             # change to current user's home folder

folder -d          # change to current user's desktop folder

folder -u jdoe -s  # change to jdoe's scripts folder

folder -?          # show help
```

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this. Please see my edit, there is something I am missing

Comment: I cannot figure out why it is ignoring my if statement

Comment: it's not the syntax, it ignores the first if statement regardless of which one.

Comment: @user14894283, the first `if` statement is part of the assignment to `$targetFolder` - it is unrelated to the `if` / `elseif` statement that follows. If you want to take action on when _no_ argument is passed, use `if ($PSBoundParameters.Count -eq 0) { ...; return }` as the first statement.

Comment: @user14894283 Thanks! That worked. Could you please explain what you did? What does if ($PSBoundParameters.Count -eq 0) { ...; return } mean and how does it work

Comment: It uses the [automatic `$PSBoundParameters` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psboundparameters) to check the count of explicitly passed arguments. `return` is needed to exit the function right then, to prevent execution of subsequent statements.

Comment: see edit for final error

Comment: @user14894283, a non-`[switch]` (non-Boolean) parameter in PowerShell _requires_ an argument - always. You can work around that for a _single_ parameter, but it is suboptimal - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58838941/45375).

Answer (score 0):

**FINALLY FIXED IT!**

I needed a flag or a tracking variable, essentially defining $targetFolder before the first if statement. I wonder if it was tryin to define the target folder as the entire if statement. See the windows documentation for multiple if statements [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-if?view=powershell-7.2)

```html
function  display-path {Get-ChildItem Env:Path }

    <# 
    **One of these can be used to navigate to the username directory. The first will only allow you to navigate to one user, the second allows for you to select the user.**
    $targetFolder = 
      if ($Username) { 
        $targetFolder += '\user\Username' #replace with your username
      } 
       
    if ($Username) { 
      Join-Path (Split-Path -LiteralPath $HOME) $Username
    } else {
      $HOME
    } #>
    function folder {
        [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Default')]
        param(    
          [Alias('u')]
          [switch] $Username
          ,
          [Alias('s')]
          [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Scripts')]
          [switch] $Scripts
          ,
          [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Desktop')]
          [Alias('d')]
          [switch] $Desktop
          ,
          [Alias('h')]
          [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'help')]
          [switch]$Help
          ,
          [Alias('r')]
          [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'root')]
          [switch]$root
        )
      
        $targetFolder =  $env:USERPROFILE
        if ($Username) { 
            $targetFolder = $env:USERPROFILE
            $u = ' -U'
          }
          elseif ($Scripts) {
          $targetFolder += '\Desktop\Scripts'
        }
          elseif ($Desktop) {
          $targetFolder += '\Desktop'
        }
          elseif ($root) {
  
            ## same as other but we can use $env:homedrive for the root of C:
        
            $targetFolder = $env:HOMEDRIVE + '\'
            $r = ' -R '
        
          }
        elseif ($Help) {
        echo "
        -H         Display help. This is the same as not typing any options.
        -U         Change to the 'Username' directory
        -S         Change to the 'scripts' directory
        -D         Change to the 'desktop' directory"
    }
        else {
        echo "
        -H         Display help. This is the same as not typing any options.
        -U         Change to the 'Username' directory
        -S         Change to the 'scripts' directory
        -D         Change to the 'desktop' directory"
    }
      
        Push-Location -LiteralPath $targetFolder
      }
```

Feel free to use this for your own navigation, thanks for the help!
Here's a github link to the code: https://github.com/semiexperienced/Windows-Powershell-Alias-and-Navigation